# Git Rebase Multiple Commit

Tags: git

I have commited my feature branch onto origin via below steps :

```
git checkout feature/feature1
git pull --all
git rebase develop 
//show commit messages
git push origin feature1
```

Now what I see, I have multiple commits are on stash that were on //show commit messages. Now I want to made one commit for all those and want to push over stash. So that for reviewer there will be only one commit to review. What are the steps should I need to follow.
Thanks

Comment: use `git rebase -i` and the squash option

Comment: so first `git rebase -i` then `git squash` then `git push origin feature/feature1` right?